# Does taking a quest from Giants incur some penalty with Dragons in one's domain (and vice versa)?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

The quest says I need do kill some of these arrogant lizards. I guess it shouldn't make lizards dwelling in my domain too happy, right? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **No**

The lizards in your domain won't care.

This isn't [age-of-wonders-planetfall](/questions/tagged/age-of-wonders-planetfall), where dwellings dislike you helping other dwellings.